# Print a PDF of spreads as single pages

Tags: print-design, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I've created an InDesign layout which contains spreads, 2 letter-size sheets side by side on each PDF "page."

I'm trying to figure out how to print the PDF so that each letter sized sheet prints onto its own letter sized page of paper. Can't figure out what Acrobat print settings to use. Or perhaps something I have to tweak in the InDesign file?

Here's the example PDF I'm trying to print: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1263007/example-spreads.pdf

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is the kind of question which might be a good fit for the proposed Graphic Design Software Support stack. Please see the proposal and follow it if you think it might be useful. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86994/graphic-design-software-support/

Comment: Hi Derrick, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export your file from InDesign as single pages.

Then in Acrobat under `File > Properties > Initial Display`, set that to *display* as two-up with cover. Save if you want this to be the default PDF view.

Close and reopen the PDF after setting the Initial View or in the View menu, choose `Page Display > Two Page view` to adjust the current open PDF

This will show spreads in Acrobat, but print as single pages.

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for your answer and your help. The problem is that I will have to **export the InDesign file as spreads,** so that the users see side-by-side pages by default. We don't want to tell every user to tweak their Acrobat view settings. 

However, for the users who will want to print the file, I would love to know if it's possible to tweak the Acrobat print settings to allow **printing of single pages,** instead of spreads. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Derrick If you set the Initial Display options in Acrobat and **save**, the end users won't have to do *anything* to view the PDF as you've configured it. **You might want to actually try this before shooting it down**. There is **no way** for Acrobat to slice a page in half for printing, and that is what you are asking if you've exported as spreads.

Comment: Oh wow. I tried it exactly how you initially described, and **that worked perfectly.** Absolutely brilliant. **Huge hi-5 to you, sir.** Enjoy your weekend!